# How can I copy a directory from one git repository to another, preserving history?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I know that I can create a new repository out of a directory of a git repository. See here: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

However, how can I copy a directory from one repository to a new directory of another completely different repository, while keeping history of that directory?

Update: is it possible for that history to show up with git log?

Comment: GitHub url is now: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subpath-out-into-a-new-repository

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this with `git filter-branch`. Basically you'd want to:

1. Split out the subpath in the first project into a new repository, using the link you've already found.
2. Push it to the second project's remote on a unique branch.
3. Fetch that branch into the second repository, then use `git filter-branch` to index-filter it into the correct subdirectory:

   ```
   git filter-branch --index-filter '
       git ls-files -sz | 
       perl -0pe "s{\t}{\tnewsubdir/}" |
       GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
           git update-index --clear -z --index-info &&
           mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
   ' HEAD
   ```
4. Finally, checkout the `master` branch of the second project (or whatever branch you're using), then merge in the newly-filtered branch.

Really not too awful an operation, all told. As AlexanderGladysh notes in the comments, you could also use a [subtree merging strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) in the place of steps 3 and 4.

Comment: Couldn't you use a subtree merge strategy instead of steps 3 and 4?

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh Yes. You could do it with a subtree merging strategy. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. I decided to go with a subtree merge strategy. One issue is that git log on that directory only shows the last merging commit not the whole history :(. Is that expected?

Comment: Regarding 3 above, --from-scratch doesn't exist in my system.

Comment: The solution with filter-branch seems to work with some tweaks: in particular, after 3, I now have duplicated each file into . and newsubdir.

Comment: @namin Yes. Only showing the merge commit as history in `git log` is a byproduct of the subtree merge strategy. It's actually why I recommended `filter-branch` instead of subtree merge.

Comment: @namin Fixed the flags on `update-index` and the command generally. I'd copied that command from a git list thread that required a specific patch to git. Sorry about that. The `--index-info` flag should work with the above modifications. If it doesn't post here and I'll try it directly. Basically it should be identical to the `filter-branch` man page but use `perl` instead of `sed`. `sed`'s interpretation of `\t` changes depending on your OS.

Comment: @Christopher could you please explain what is being done in step 3? And do I need perl to execute this command?

Comment: @Maheep -- step 3 iproceeds through the repositories history, writing the git index out to a new file while substituting in the new directory path with each commit. It then uses a plumbing command called 'git update-index' to update git's index at each commit to inject the new, substituted index. You don't need 'perl'. It'll also work with 'sed'. Just mind your tab-characters (if you're on a mac, you've got BSD sed, if you're on a linux system, probably GNU).